# python 3.6 - variable inside fstring with datetime function

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, integer, f-string

I am trying the run below lines of code in a loop and want to define the timedelta as a variable as it will keep varying.

```
START_TIME = f"{datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(int('%d')):%d/%m/%Y 00:00}" % COUNT
END_TIME = f"{datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(int('%d')):%d/%m/%Y 23:59}" % COUNT
```

However, this is failing with below error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '%d'
```

I am trying to get start and end time of the day for past few days and do some action over it. I tried few other ways too but did not work.

Comment: Converting to a string should be your  last step. A combination of replace and timedelta should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was indeed approaching this inside out. Got it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because string formatting (solving the expressions in `{}`) is executed before the printf-style substitution (`string % object`).

Although it seems to be a bit less readable, it might be better to rearrange your code - calculate `START_TIME`, `END_TIME` first and then convert everything to strings.

If you need to have them in one line each, you could also use brackets and call the `string.format()` method explicitly to ensure it's done last. The following very generall example will work:

`("{%d}" % 0).format('Hello')`

Output:
`Hello`

However, given your examples this will still not be very readable.